# how to set up nat and host only to access server from other computer virtual box

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, virtualbox, netplan

i want to create my own server on virtual box.

i already add NAT and HOST-ONLY in virtual box.

and this is ip from virtual box host-only
Adapter

```
ipv4 address = 192.168.56.1
netmask = 255.255.255.0
```

dhcp server

```
server address = 192.168.56.100
netmask = 255.255.255.0
lower address bound = 192.168.56.101
upper address bound = 192.168.56.254
```

and this ip in my ubuntu server. i setting ip from file  `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
        enp0s8:
            addresses: [192.168.56.2/24]
            dhcp4: no
    version: 2
```

i can access it in same computer, but i cant access from other computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access from other computer, why don't you just use bridged network?  This is best suitable in your condition.

For host-only network, you can by no means access to other computers or access from other computers.

As for NAT, even host and guest cannot talk to each other without [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward).

Please refer the Official [Virtual Network document](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) and think again what are you trying to do.

Comment: This worked for me after seeing a lot of forums recommending host-only & NAT. For 18.04, after you set to bridged network in virtualBox, start up your VM in GUI mode and go to Settings > Network > [Wired settings]  > IPV4 and set your desired static IP, etc. Reboot and validate your network connection with `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`